# Failed to compile values file' when i try to run my app

Tags: java, android

I am building a note taking app and suddenly i'm getting this error when i try to run the app.

Error:

Dependencies using groupId 'com.android.support' and 'androidx.*' can not be combined but found 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' and 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4' incompatible dependencies

This is my build.graddle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bundgaard.rememory"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:21.0.1'
    implementation 'co.roverlabs:picasso:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
}
```

I can't figure out where theese two groupId's clash...

Comment: Try replacing `co.roverlabs:picasso:2.5.2` with `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Perfect - that seemed to do the trick. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`co.roverlabs:picasso:2.5.2` is a very out-of-date fork of [Square's Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). It has dependencies on similarly out-of-date support libraries from Google. Switching to an official Picasso release may help, particularly if it is one that is up to date.